# React-native-svg loading animated svg file from url

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I am using "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0" and am opening svg this way:

```
<SvgCssUri uri={imageURL} style={imageStyle} height={height} width={width} />
```

If the svg on url is animated, the animation is not shown in my application. If I click on the link and open it in browser it works as it should. Does anyone have any advice on this or already had this problem and solved it? Or if anyone knows if this npm is maybe not meant to load animated svg files?

Comment: If React has (yet another) failing library; is it maybe better than to contact the creators of that failing code: https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg/issues

Comment: Yes did that, got no answer